# iOS push notIfication using PHP?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, cordova

First off, I do apologies if this question shouldn't be asked here. please let me know and I will delete it.

I'm trying to create an `iOS app` using `jquery mobile` and for the server side I will be using `PHP/MYSQL` and will package it via `phonegap`.

I am totally new in implementing *push notification* in the app so I wouldn't know where to start.

The issue that I have is that I need to implement a Push Notification in the app.

I have been searching and reading a lot of blogs and stuff on Google and I can't seem to find a straight forward and clear information about implementing Push Notification using PHP or by any other means (I prefer PHP as I will be doing a lot of MYSQL/PHP stuff).

could someone please point me to a tutorial of some sort that will walk me through the steps from start to finish?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using phonegap to package your app I suggest using push notification phonegap plug in. Here are a few tutorials for it and the project on github:

Here is a tutorial: http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

Here is the project: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: https://www.shift8web.ca/blog/2015/08/use-php-to-send-apns-ios-and-gcm-android-push-notifications/

Comment: also, i came across both of those links. still doesn't explain everything in detail! it assumes the reader knows what they are doing as opposed to explaining it for people like myself who have no experience at all.

Comment: and one more thing, i thought about using phonegap push notification plugin but then I won't have be able to access the MYSQL database via phonegap as it is a javascript plugin so I need to use PHP.

Comment: You cannot use php with phonegap, unless you are calling the script using javascript. When you get the response you can pass it to the plug in and make the push notification.

Comment: do you mean I cannot package my app files (all .php files) with phonegap?

Comment: Yes you cannot, phonegap just accepts HTML, CSS and JS http://phonegap.com/about/faq/ "A: A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes while the device is connected to the Internet."

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up, it seems like I can use jQuery AJAX calls to get the data from the PHP though! http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/jquery_ajax_call_using_php_will_that_work_with_phonegap

Comment: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/bq028eo7th1d4